# Chrome syncFileSystem and app ID

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, storage, google-chrome-app

I am working on the same app on multiple machines and keeping the code synced through google drive. But they have separate app IDs on separate machines and I just started using the chrome synFileSystem API which is putting the files in separate sandboxes. So I can't sync data between clients while developing. Is there a way to ensure the same app ID between clients when they are unpacked in developer mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can a "key" property in your manifest.json like this :

"key": "MUGfMA0GCSqGSI... ...AIZQIDAQAB",

More informations : http://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/key.html

Comment: I had actually given up and saved the file locally in my google drive folder, but this is great, cant wait to look into it and fix it soon, thank you!